# Convert 2-tuple to 3-tuple Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

So I have a list of tuples:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

for example. And I perform a calculation on its elements. The result of this should be joined to this tuple, but I don't know how.

```
[(1,2,103),(2,3,809),(3,4,2034)]
```

is the format I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a calculation function like:

```
calculate :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

you can do

```
calculateAll :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
calculateAll = map (\(x, y) -> (x, y, calculate x y))
```

or more generally:

```
calculateAllWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b, c)]
calculateAllWith f = map (\(x, y) -> (x, y, f x y))
```

Comment: Why the lambdas? Why not just use `calculateAll = map calculate` and `calculateAllWith f = map f`?

Comment: @mhwombat, because `calculate` or `f` have type `a -> b -> c`, not `(a, b) -> (a, b, c)`.

Comment: Accepting this answer because the right signature is used for `calculate` function, and it works as it is. Thanks.

Comment: @Vladimir D'oh! I get it now. I wrongly assumed that the OP's function had the signature `(a, b) -> (a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 6):

A quite straightforward solution:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<*>))

mapResultOn3rd :: (a -> b -> c) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b,c)]
mapResultOn3rd f = map (uncurry (,,) <*> uncurry f)
```

For example, in ghci:

```
>>> mapResultOn3rd (:) [(1,[2]), (3,[4,5])]
[(1,[2],[1,2]),(3,[4,5],[3,4,5])]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `map` function:

```
calc :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
calc = error "Implement me"

calcList :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
calcList = map calc
```

Comment: I think this solution is the most straightforward. In case you're not familiar with point-free notation, that last line is equivalent to `calcList xs = map calc xs`

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use a list comprehension in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let list = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
Prelude> [(x,y,x*y) | (x,y) <- list]
[(1,2,2),(2,3,6),(3,4,12)]
```

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension

Or use the list as a monad:

```
Prelude> do (x,y) <- list; return (x,y,x*y)
[(1,2,2),(2,3,6),(3,4,12)]
```

But I prefer the list comprehension :-)

Comment: By the way this was how I ended up doing it.